# using a bool in a WWWForm unity

Tags: forms, unity-game-engine

So Im trying to add a boolean field to a WWWForm to send to my server.  The problem is that there is no bool param option.  When I try using a string option I get errors as well from the server.  any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use int for storing your boolean field.

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
form.AddField ("bool", 0);
```

Ideally string should also work, dont know what may be the issue. You should post your code and error log for further help I think.

Answer (score 0):

send a int and then convert the int to a bool on your server

```html
WWWForm f = new WWWForm();
f.addField("int",0);
```

on your server(php example)

```html
$int = $_POST['int'];

if($int == 1){
  $bool = true;
}else{
  $bool = false;
}

//do somethig with $bool
```